# ResponseEntity ignored on JSON documentation with springdoc-openApi

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

I try to generate a JSON documentation with springdoc-openApi
i have a controller with return type is ResponseEntity
something like this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "my-path",produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
@Tag(name = "Path Check", description = "Path Controller")
@Slf4j
public class PathController {


    @PostMapping(produces = "*/*", consumes = "*/*")
    @Operation(summary = "get path check")
    public **ResponseEntity**<Object> pathCheck() {
        .....
    }

}
```

i'm looking to have, in my json generated, something like this in components section :

```
"ResponseEntity": {
                "title": "ResponseEntity",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "body": {
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "statusCode": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "ACCEPTED",
                            ...
                            "VARIANT_ALSO_NEGOTIATES"
                        ]
                    },
                    "statusCodeValue": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    }
                }
            }
```